# Linq - how to subtract current index DateTime item with previous index DateTime item

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning Linq these days. I was searching for this answer on stackoverflow or Google, but didn't find what I need.

Flight class:

```
public class Flight
{
    public IList<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Segment class:

```
public class Segment
{
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
}
```

Each flight consists of one or more segments. Flight with one segment is like this: Venice - Philadelphia. Flight with two segments is Venice - Philadelphia, Philadelphia - San Francisco. There can be more than 2 segments too.

I have to sum the time between Segment2.DepartureDate and Segment1.ArrivalDate, to calculate the time differnce between arrival and next departure in all segments.

I made this for string with foreach and conditions like this:

```
public string FilterFlights(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (var flight in flights)
    {
    var indexItem = 0;
    DateTime previousArrivalDateTime = new DateTime();
    TimeSpan timeSpan;

    int time = 0;
    foreach (var segments in flight.Segments)
    {
        if (indexItem == 0)
        {
        previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
        s = s + "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
        }

        if (indexItem > 0)
        {
        timeSpan = segments.DepartureDate - previousArrivalDateTime;
        time += timeSpan.Hours;
        s = s + "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
        previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
        }
        indexItem++;
    }
    //d = 0;

    if (time > 2)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    return s;
}
```

I now want to actually create new method and instead string, to return `IEnumerable<Flight>` and I found out that it's the best to use LinQ. I was alread sniffing around with ElementAt method, but didn't know what actually am I doing.

**EDIT:**
This is how far I got with my linq method:

```
public IEnumerable<Flight> FilterFlightsWithTwoHoursPlusGap(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
{
    int totalGap = 0;

    return from flight in flights
       //wrong where syntax, don't know how to
    where flight.Segments.Select((y, index) =>
        totalGap +=
            (index == 0)
            ? totalGap = 0
            : (y.DepartureDate - flight.Segments.ElementAt(index - 1).ArrivalDate).Hours
        ).Where(totalGap < 2) // if gap is lower than 2 hours(calculated from timespans between departure current and arrival previous
    select flight; //return flights
}
```

So any advice would be nice.

PS: Any good site for learning linq or ebooks?

Comment: This is an aside - but if you're actually doing this in real life then you should not be using the `DateTime` type.  You will have errors around daylight saving time changes.  You should use `DateTimeOffset` instead, or look in to [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) using `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` types.

Comment: it always help! i will check it!

Answer (score 4):

## Query

If you want to get the `TimeSpan`s for each of the waiting periods between consecutive `Flight` `Segment`s, you can use this:

```
Flight flight = ...;
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> query = flight.Segments
    .SelectPairs((a, b) => b.DepartureDate - a.ArrivalDate);
```

For a `Flight` with N `Segments`, this will give you N - 1 `TimeSpan`s.

**Edit:** If you want to get the total  amount of waiting time between all `Segment`s on a `Flight`, you can augment the LINQ query like this:

```
TimeSpan totalWaitingTime = flight.Segments
    .SelectPairs((a, b) => b.DepartureDate - a.ArrivalDate)
    .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (s, t) => s + t);
```

## Helper

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectPairs(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, TResult> selector)
{
    var first = true;
    var prev = default(T);
    foreach (var curr in source)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return selector(prev, curr);
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
}
```

### Note

You may be tempted to define `SelectPairs` as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectPairs(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, TResult> selector)
{
    return Enumerable.Zip(source, source.Skip(1), selector);
}
```

The pitfall here is that the `source` will be enumerated twice. If that's acceptable in your scenario (e.g., if `source` is just a `List<T>`), then go for it. But if it's not, then the longer definition above will be better.

Comment: Could you use `source.Skip(1)` to get rid of the `first`?

Comment: @ChrisBednarski Not without enumerating `source` twice. :-/ If you're willing to do that, then the body of `SelectPairs` could just be `return Enumerable.Zip(source, source.Skip(1), selector);`. See my edit.

Comment: Nice solution Chris.  A little simpler than iterating the `IEnumerator` manually, as I was about to do, since you don't have to check for empty sequence and such.

Comment: @Corey, this isn't my answer :) However, `SkipWhile` doesn't enumerate forever so may be used to optimize differently. See answer below

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your tip. I actually want to get time gap between segments(from timespan). You get this by TimeSpan as you said, but I am curious if you can do this in one linq query, because if I get TimeSpan, I have to foreach again etc. This is mine example but syntax is not right: http://pastebin.com/pQFJsL00 it's more like pseudo-code .

Comment: @JohnMathilda I've updated my answer to reflect that extra step. You can add on a call to `Aggregate` to the end of the LINQ query.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please explain about how to properly fill types in `public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectPairs(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, TResult> selector)` ?